# PHP; sum of returned numbers from eBay API is invalid

Tags: php, ebay-api

I seem to be having an issue with PHP rounding (sort of) numbers by default, I am calling the eBay API and getting back the price of an item and the postage. I need to add these two numbers before entering them into my database, the issue seems to be when I add the two numbers up they come back with a strange value:

```
shipping = 5.95
item price = 18.55
```

If I add the two up I get a result of `23`.

```
$ship = $item->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost;
$price = $item->sellingStatus->currentPrice;
$sell = ($ship + $price);
```

Do I need to tell php the returned value is a number?

Comment: Are "shippingServiceCost" and "currentPrice" strings?

Comment: Double check that the decimal point is a "." rather than a "·"

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply, it looks like they were coming back as strings, I have changed the to floats as described below and all seems to work fine.
Cheers,
David
Cheers,

Comment: What does `var_dump($ship, $price);` give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure both of your values are actually integers or floats, instead of strings. Summing strings to eachother could result in strange behavior.

Try this:

```
$ship = (float) $item->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost;
$price = (float) $item->sellingStatus->currentPrice;
$sell = ($ship + $price);
```

Now $sell should consist of a float. You can use `(float)` to cast the variable to a floating variable.

Comment: Hi stefandoorn,

This had worked perfect, thank you.
I will try and do some reading now I know the correct terms to search for.

Kind Regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [typecasting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in general, as is quite important in a variety of scenarios for you as a PHP developer.

Comment: Hi Elzo,
Thanks for the tip, I will have a read up.

Cheers,
David

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the $ship is a string with `5.95` .. that would be properly converted to float but I think it is .. `5,95` and that would be converted to 5

```
<?php
$ship = "5,95";
$price = "18,55";
$sell = ($ship + $price);
echo "$sell = ($ship + $price)";

?>
```

output:

```
23 = (5,95 + 18,55)
```

convert:

```
<?php
$ship = (float) "5,95";
$price = (float) "18,55";
$sell = ($ship + $price);
echo "$sell = ($ship + $price)";
?>
```

output:

23 = (5 + 18)

Use:

```
$ship = str_replace(',','.',$ship);
$price = str_replace(',','.',$price);
```

And it should work!

Comment: Hi rauschen,
Thanks for the reply but the prices do come back with a "." and the first method worked fine.
Cheers,